# Redefine \label and \ref commands so that they also work without having to be next to a \caption or \captionof

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

I've been trying to use `\label` and `\ref` neither after a `\caption` nor `\captionof`, like so:

```
Figure \Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure}: The caption % A manually created caption
\label{fig:the_ref_name} % the ref that sould ref the \Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure} number
```

Is there a way to use this pair of commands without having them to be after `\caption` or `\captionof`, but such that I don't lose the ability to continue referencing equations, figures, tables and all the things you would normally?

Comment: How would LaTeX determine what to reference if it is not inside an element like a figure or table? Would you like to reference the most recent element, or something else? Could you make a small example document showing where you want to place the `\label` and what you want the output to be in that example?

Comment: In order to result in the correct value from a `\ref`, there has to be something to "hang it on", which is usually a counter of some sort.  So unless you establish a reliable "hanger", what you want to do would be nearly impossible.  I'm sure this has been explained in an existing question/answer.

Comment: @Marijn I've edited the post with an example. Thank you.

Comment: you can do `\makeatletter\def\@currentlabel{\Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure}\makeatother\label{...}`, but it would be easier to use `\refstepcounter{figure}` and then `Figure \thefigure`:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\label` command stores a value for the label based on the internal macro `\@currentlabel`. This macro is set by commands like `\section` and environments like `\begin{figure}`. However, you can also set it yourself, and then the next `\label` command will take the value you have specified.

Because `\@currentlabel` is an internal macro containing the `@` symbol, you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around the code in which you use the macro. The following MWE assigns a value to the macro using `\edef` (expanded define), which makes sure the counters are represented by the actual values.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\setcounter{figure}{8} % set the figure counter to some number for illustration purposes
Figure \Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure}: The caption % A manually created caption
\makeatletter\edef\@currentlabel{\Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}\makeatother% set value for use by \label
\label{fig:the_ref_name} % assign the label
\section{New section}
As we have seen in Figure \ref{fig:the_ref_name}, figures can have captions.
\end{document}
```

Result (after two compilations to write the label to the auxiliary file and read it back in):

[image]

The code above is intended to illustrate the principle of setting the internal label value and subsequently assigning this to a label like `fig:the_ref_name`. However, this is of course not very practical. You can write a small macro to generate the caption and set the label value simultaneously:

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customfigcaption}[1]{%
Figure \Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure}: #1%
\edef\@currentlabel{\Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\setcounter{figure}{8}
\customfigcaption{The caption}
\label{fig:the_ref_name} % assign the label
\section{New section}
As we have seen in Figure \ref{fig:the_ref_name}, figures can have captions.
\end{document}
```

The output is the same as above.

A final addition is to add a phantom section that allows the label to be referenced by `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\customfigcaption}[1]{%
Figure \Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure}: #1%
\csname phantomsection\endcsname%
\edef\@currentlabel{\Roman{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\setcounter{figure}{5}
\customfigcaption{The caption}
\label{fig:the_ref_name} % assign the label
\section{New section}
As we have seen in Figure \ref{fig:the_ref_name}, figures can have captions.
\end{document}
```

[image]